# List All Data Sent to View

Tags: node.js, express

How would you go about logging a list of all the data that's exposed to an Express.js view?

Basically I'd had some view errors that basically said that the fields I was using hadn't been defined.  I've since figured out the issue, but when I was looking around to log all the data that had been sent to the view, I wasn't able to find a solution.

Is there a way of logging this?  I'd tried logging the `global` object, but it only gave me the built-in Node.js globals, not the data that's actually sent to the views.

Example:

### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    I_WOULD_IMAGINE_YOU_COULD_LOG_THIS_SOMEHOW : "right?"
  });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

### index.jade

```
doctype

body
  h1 Test Page, Check Server Logs

  - console.log(global)

  - // Being able to log the data that's available
  - // would be helpful for tricky view errors that
  - // arise from time to time.
```

Comment: Please provide the routes code.

Comment: @scopsy I don't see how providing the route would help.  I want to log all the data that's being provided from the `res.render()` call from inside the view.  If you need routing code, you can find one in the last code exmaple here:  http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: You want to access the object data passed as the second argument on the render function ? (If not, I guess im not really getting your question)

Comment: Correct, I was wondering how I could log the data passed into the view, from inside the view.  I thought the `global` option would include it, but after I tested it out the data wasn't being supplied there.  I'll update my post to show you an example of what I mean.

Comment: You could try following:  res.locals.global = {app: app.locals, res: res.locals} befor res.render and than in view you get global.app and global.res